# Tag Synonym Proposal: [mean-stack] [mean.io] [meanjs]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

There's a relatively new web development stack which has too many tags about it, and a lot of them are mislabeled.

This is the tag info for [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack), which I edited:

> The MEAN stack is a methodology that employs MongoDB, Express,
>   AngularJS and Node.js to provide a complete end-to-end system. One of
>   the primary motivations of such a stack is that it is pure JavaScript
>   at all ends. Two different implementations are available:
>   http://mean.io and http://meanjs.org/

I think that [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack) should be the main tag, and [mean.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean.io) and [meanjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meanjs) should be merged into [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack).  They are slightly different forked implementations of the same stack, and questions are very rarely about anything where it makes a difference which implementation you're using.  If the implementation does make a difference to the question, I think that's best expressed in the title rather than in the tags.

There used to be another tag, [meanio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meanio) (without the dot), which I manually eliminated by re-tagging all of the questions that used to be tagged [meanio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meanio).

Then one last issue is the people who are using the [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) tag.  This tag is supposed to indicate arithmetic mean, but some are misusing it instead of [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack).  This misuse is of course a little tough to track down, but this search of [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) AND [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) shows 20 questions which are definitely mislabeled: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean+node.js

I would do all of this myself, but I don't have enough reputation to propose tag synonyms, or to edit posts without moderator approval.