# Tag cleanup request: replace [mean] with [mean-stack] when the post is not about the arithmetic mean

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

**Here is the basic premise of my tag cleanup request:** I have been reading posts tagged [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) to see if they should actually be tagged [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack) or many just have [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) removed from them. [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) is the arithmetic mean, while many posters actually are asking about the MEAN stack.

### How did I discover the need for this tag cleanup?

I had been searching for things about developing using the MEAN stack, and I was going to post something about it and tag it [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) when I noticed that the tag [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) was for the arithmetic mean. Others have clearly had a similarly confusing experience since there were lots of posts that had [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean), but were not about arithmetic mean at all. Sometimes, you can tell by reading that the post is really about using the MEAN stack. Sometimes, it is really about mean.io or some other taggable thing. If it's already tagged with [mean.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean.io), but also has [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean), I've been just removing [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) sometimes. I noticed that someone else also thought maybe confusion between [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) and [mean-stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean-stack) was a bit problematic: [Tag Synonym Proposal: [mean-stack] [mean.io] [meanjs]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258259/3842582)

### Why not just edit the tags?

That is what I started out doing - editing the tags myself. I was trying to clean up tags that are completely incorrect (completely off topic) for a topic I care about. I have been submitting these edits in groups when I have time. I have had some rejections recently. The reasoning for the rejection seems to be that the change is not substantive enough. I disagree with that judgement. Leaving that edit undone means that there is a tag for something on that post that is completely unrelated to it. I also have the sense that the people rejecting the edits are frustrated with my suggestions. I don't understand why they don't want to see that tag removed when it is wrong.

### Is it *really* a tag cleanup request?

I honestly don't know if this is really a tag cleanup request. I noticed in the comments on [What constitutes "Too Minor" when it comes to tag editing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255951/3842582) that one can request the cleanup of a tag. This is essentially what I'd like to see happen. But, I kind of wish I didn't need to have all of those edit rejections in order to have discovered that idea.

---

I am still relatively new to Stack Overflow, so please help me improve my post here if this is not the way to get this cleaned up. I was happy doing the edits by hand, but the rejection got frustrating and I don't want to be a bother. I just want the tags to be right! I'm not sure I'm even tagging this correctly. I don't think it's as simple as a find and replace. It's not a merge of two tags. And, I'm not saying [mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mean) should go away. I felt like I was actually providing a useful service, but apparently there were several others who felt my retagging was annoying or inappropriate.

Comment: Can you add a short version of what you ask?

Comment: I have edited the post to pull the request to the top. I'm not sure if the rest is really needed or not, but I felt I should explain the situation a little bit because I'm not sure if this is really what is needed. I just know that I don't mind making edits of this tag, but I don't appreciate being rejected when I'm making these edits. I'm being careful and making sure the [mean] tag doesn't belong, but if there is some better way to do it, I'm happy to try.

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed several of your edits.

They *are* too minor, and you shouldn't be getting +2 reputation for merely robo-adding a tag to posts for the same reason. **If there were nothing else wrong with the posts you reviewed, the edits would be fine, but that wasn't the case**.

For example, look at [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5662675): there are grammar, formatting, *and* clarity issues that should have been corrected, and all that you did was remove a tag. I should have used the "too minor" reject reason, but I used the "vandalism" reason because I saw that you were doing this to many posts in succession. I hoped that the use of that reason would catch your attention since I had already left a custom reason on a previous edit telling you why they were being rejected.

Your edits were by no means "annoying or inappropriate." In fact, such edits are welcomed and I appreciate that you were trying to help out here. Because you gain reputation for edits, you need to make them substantial so that they can make it through the review queue and so that they are worth the rep you are awarded as a result of their acceptance.

I understand where you're going with this, but the proper action to take is to post here on Meta, which you have done, so that users with full editing privileges (2k+ reputation) can do retags for you (we don't get reputation for our edits and they don't go through a review queue).

Comment: I am bummed that some rejectors of the edits said - "This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate." I wish that the custom rejection notice had come to me as a message so that I would have noticed that I could do a tag cleanup request earlier. It's really hard to get up the courage to ask a real question around here when you're new. I was trying to participate in a legitimate, helpful way in order to learn more about the site and how it works. I was happy to be gaining reputation points while doing something I thought was helpful. The rejection hurt.

Comment: Also, bumping, reviewer time, edit histories.

Comment: @PrairieProf In retrospect, that was a bit harsh, but this happens *a lot*: people find a tag that needs cleanup and they see it as an opportunity to farm rep. They will go through every question in the tag and retag it to something else without fixing the rest of the post, gaining +2 rep each time. The problem is less that people do that and **more that people in the review queues do not stop them and mindlessly approve these edits without giving feedback**. What you were doing **is** helpful and legitimate, but there are too many people who do not have the same mindset as you and instead...

Comment: ...wish to abuse the system for the sole purpose of gaining reputation. At a certain point, we get fed up with dealing with these people and make assumptions of the user's intent because we're so accustomed to seeing people doing this for purposes that are less idyllic than yours.

Comment: I get it. And, really, I _was_ farming reputation in the beginning, because I didn't even have enough reputation to up vote something. I was waaaaay too scared to ask a question, so I thought in that I would at least try to be useful while I'm learning. I see that someone else had the suggestion of custom edits going to the inbox, so now I've up voted that. Of course, that only helps if the reviewers say, "Hey, why not make a tag cleanup request? Here's how:" instead of "quit making mass edits", which I didn't find helpful (and didn't notice right away either).

Comment: @PrairieProf We [discussed this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/edit-rejection-notices) in [the Meta.SE Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and we mostly agree that there should be notices for rejection because it would inform the editor not just that their edits were rejected, but *why*.

Comment: There is notification of rejected edits when you go to type a new edit elsewhere, but *if the comments in the rejections are not helpful* it doesn't really matter. I could see that people said the edits were too minor. *But, I felt they were wrong.* I had looked up some posts about editing tags and had the impression that, while there is some disagreement about it, it is generally considered appropriate when the tag is _wrong_ and you are _removing_ it. If someone had suggested a tag cleanup request, I would have at least been able to know there was a more acceptable way of doing this.

Answer (score -2):

In contradiction to my fellow community member @AstroCBs behaviour: it would be a bad idea to consider you as farming or hoarding +2 rep; remember it is just magical unicorn points no need to get worked up over people who just like to keep a clean and organised folder.

I think the main problem is that when you do an edit you involve at least 5 more people who, as they most likely see it, have bigger and better fires to tackle than your retagging (brutual but honest). As @AstroCB says: this is where you should involve the community and:

- Get confirmation of a tag request
- Get a high rep user to do it

Either way, even if you are of rep, do not go off and retag yourself. You will be seen as a troller and (quite) possibly suspended.

Do everything that big with a post here and get the community to acknowledge it.

So my sum up: I have smypathy, you are geniunely trying to help and I won't attack you for making this request, although I cannot answer it since I am not a user of that tag, you are still new and your request shouldn't be met with blunt but instead insightful critism.

So, yes, if you think something needs a retag just post it here, don't go off and do it yourself.

#### Edit

One problem I can see with this request is that mean as in the math might actually be a minor tag, I cannot think of how a question being tagged about the mean of something can stop me from answering/help me to answer.