# Massive add of TSQL tag

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Since I have had access to the Suggested Edit review queue I've been getting quite a lot of edits that just add the tag  [tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tsql) to [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) questions. Most of these edits come from a single user.

I'm not really sure of what to do with these. I'm competent in SQL, but not specifically in MS SQL-Server. Should all `sql-server` questions be also tagged with `tsql`, even if they do not pose specific `tsql` problems? If so, then couldn't this be solved with some tag synonyms?

I'm not sure this can be rejected as a minor edit, since it concerns tags. I would think that `tsql` experts would also have `sql-server` among their favorite tags. So I don't actually think this is for improved visibility of posts.

For now I'll skip these edits.

Comment: A tag edit can be too minor (not sure about this specific case). Chances are that user is just hoarding rep.

Comment: I personally reject them as too minor if I see something that wasn't improved even if I think the added tag is relevant. If I think the added tag is not very relevant then I reject such edits as too minor even if I don't see anything that could be improved.

Comment: I've been skipping them as well. For practical purposes that means that the overwhelming majority of the edits will be approved, although at least it won't have my name on it. Thankfully that user is almost at 2k rep, so they'll stop then.

Comment: @Boann The drawback of that user hitting 2K is that they'll now get to approve other people's sloppy edits... The problem will get worse and worse, until we have better audits in the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: A question tagged MSSQL and SQL pretty much implies t-sql...T-SQL being the flavour of SQL Microsoft uses.  It's almost as helpful as tagging the question as 'english' because the text of the question is in-fact written in English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find that, when users do this, they often *do not know that they are doing anything wrong*. They think that they're helping out and do not realize that just adding a tag is not worth two reputation.

Rejecting the edit is the way to go, but what you really want to do is leave a custom reason and explain that mass retags are not good suggested edits unless they fix **all of the issues with the post**. You should also @reply them on one of the posts (any users in the edit history of a post can be pinged from its comments) and explain it, because users are not immediately notified if their edit is rejected and they don't always check.

Also, see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270299/3366929) about a similar case.

Comment: These edits fix nothing in the posts.  Only a tag is added.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg New users really don't know how to tag posts, so retags are usually necessary. However, they are usually too minor because they don't fix everything wrong with the post.

Comment: "They think that they're helping out and do not realize that just adding a tag is not worth two reputation." I disagree. If *properly* retagging a question is not worth two points of reputation, then the SO system should NOT be awarding two points for this type of job. Please do not go after the users who try to help, but rather raise this question (if you feel it's needed) with the SO devels (e.g. to avoid only one point for retags). It's bad practice to discourage users to do useful work in the first place.

Comment: @landroni Exactly: you have to tell them that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just reject these as too minor.

Whilst the edit isn't actually wrong the benefit of adding this tag to questions already tagged `sql-server` is extremely minor or entirely non existent.

Certainly not worth three reviewers' time to evaluate.

Comment: If this is the case, then wouldn't it be better for someone to contact this specific user and talk it over? Today there were over 10 of these edits, and every day there are more. He adds his standard "Added TSQL tag" note even to suggested edits in which he has not done that, but maybe fixed formatting or english or other things.

Comment: @Frazz The user should be contacted, in my opinion; these kind of mass-edits are not a good thing to do, and should be brought up to the community first.

Answer (score 0):

Too minor.

There's a myth that anything concerning tags isn't minor and is hugely beneficial to the site. But no.

Yeah, the system's broken, so you should ping the editor. Speaking of pinging, you can ping the reviewers too. Invite them [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58120/please-dont-approve-minor-or-invalid-edits).

Comment: I don't think the myth is that "anything concerning tags isn't minor", it is that *certain, specific* tag edits are not too minor merely because they focus on the tags. If a C++ question were mistagged Java, fixing that would be a high priority and hugely beneficial. Adding extra tags doesn't carry the same weight. (Granted, though, I'm not saying you shouldn't *also* fix the other problems with a post. I just might not uncheck the "this edit was helpful" box when I clicked "Improve".)